# Metal contacts that protrude out of Ethernet connector mounted on PCB

Tags: connector, ethernet

Here is an image of an Ethernet connector that is mounted on PCBs:

[image]

Near the front of the connector, there are two metal contacts that are protruding out at the top side and the right side as visible in the image. What is the purpose of these? How come they are not present on all ethernet connectors if they are important?

Someone said that these exist to make contact with chassis and it implies that they are somehow meant to help with EMC and ESD problems. But they don't exist on all Ethernet connectors. I have not seen such protruding metal on other connects e.g USB. So I am not sure what their purpose really is.

Answer (score 11):

The advice that you received is correct.
The connector can slide into a hole in e.g. a metal chassis or shield to provide a continuous noise / RF shield.

They are not on all such connectors as making them this way costs more and not everyone needs (or considers that they need) this degree of shielding in their application.

They are more likely to be used in either high performance or high noise sensitivity environments.

A few examples

[Belfuse 60300 Series Jacks](https://www.belfuse.com/resources/datasheets/stewartconnector/ds-stw-60300-series-jacks.pdf)

They say:

- . Stewart Connector is the only manufacturer to provide reliable 10GBase-T Ethernet in a passive connector application
- The 60300 series is one of the only RJ45 connectors on the market
  today which has the electrical performance characteristics required to
  deliver 10GBase-T Ethernet signals.

Amphenol may disagree with them.

Note that only half the series have panel grounds and that they are specifically mentioned in this table.

[image]

---

Molex "Jack Modular Connector 8p8c (RJ45, Ethernet) 90° Angle (Right) Shielded, **EMI Finger** Cat3 [here](https://tools.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/438600001_sd.pdf)
Digikey product page [here](https://www.digikey.co.nz/short/97mr384v)

---

TE Connectivity [here](https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-6339191-5.datasheet.pdf)
[Product page](https://www.digikey.co.nz/short/mntfwpwd)
Panel grounds specifically mentioned in datasheet.

---

> I don't see them on other connectors like USB, HDMI e.t.c. So I am not sure why they are only appearing on Ethernet connectors and that also only some of them. Don't other connectors ever need to have such shielding effect?

As above, it depends on application, environment, data rate, cost sensitivity and more.

[Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=metal+shielded+hdmi+connectors&sca_esv=577807614&tbm=isch&sxsrf=AM9HkKmy8zEb1myRa3CoNNuO3QJ884-Mng:1698671255512&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinkJnG652CAxXwr1YBHfCPAI0Q_AUoAnoECAIQBA&biw=1234&bih=1060&dpr=1.75) are some variably shielded HDMI connectors.

Comment on USB shielding [here](https://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/article/usb-cables-shielding-matters-as-well)

And various variably well shielded ones [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=metal+shielded+usb+connectors&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiN_YLV652CAxWl5TgGHXziCMUQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=metal+shielded+usb+connectors&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoECCMQJ1DPGFjmIWDGI2gAcAB4AIAB7gGIAfEIkgEDMi01mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=tqo_ZY3KJKXL4-EP_MSjqAw&bih=1060&biw=1234).

> Also, often the chassis is not even metal. I am not sure why someone would make a chassis out of non-conducting material. Does not make sense.

That's a different question. If the chassis is non conductive then you'd not need the shielding fingers. All well designed USB sockets have the shell grounded to a PCB ground plane. A chassis and/or panel shield may or may not be needed depending on factors that I mentioned above.

Comment: I don't see them on other connectors like USB, HDMI e.t.c. So I am not sure why they are only appearing on Ethernet connectors and that also only some of them. Don't other connectors ever need to have such shielding effect? Also, often the chassis is not even metal. I am not sure why someone would make a chassis out of non-conducting material. Does not make sense.

Comment: Actually they can exist the other way around, it you look at the backplate for a motherboard for example.

Comment: @gyuunyuu The RJ45 connector is somewhat infamous for causing EMC issues due to its large size and awkward shape. As a result, metal shielding is relatively more common on things like switches than for other connectors and so you tend to see the connectors designed accordingly.

Comment: @MiNiMe, what do you mean by "they can exist the other way around"? By backplate you mean the plate that is part of the enclosure and has holes in it for the different connectors that exist on the PCB and will be connected to using harness/cable of some sort?

Comment: Yes, and they also have protruding metal things as seen in this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9850/what-is-the-purpose-of-an-io-shield-on-a-computer-case so it grounds to the different connectors metal shielding

Answer (score 5):

These are ground/EMI fingers that are used to make good connection with a metal case, for many reasons, such as EMI, ESD, and grounding and shielding.

The smaller the gap or hole on a back panel for a connector, the less it will leak EMI, out of or into the system.

An important detail is that on the connector you posted, the metal is folded also on the inside of the RJ45 socket, which means that when you have a proper shielded CAT cable with proper RJ45 plug with a metal shield, this connector will connect the metal chassis also to CAT cable shield through the RJ45 shielded plug.

Not all devices have metal cases so not all connectors need to have these EMI fingers, most likely your home wireless router has plastic case and plastic connector without metal case around the connector, and the router is also likely not grounded either, it has a power supply with no ground contact on mains plug. But in a typical home you would also use non-shielded flexible cables between eqipment in a room, and only the fixed cabling between rooms may be shielded.